# gdb on linux does not use 2's complement

Tags: c, gdb

Today When I was debugging use gdb. I discovered something really strange:

```
print 0xC0 //192, correct
print (char)0xC0 //-64
```

Doesn't computer use 2's complement to represent negative numbers (which is obviously not this case) or I am missing something fundamentally?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is definitely using two's complement, the fact that your `char` cast (and, in this implementation, `char` is obviously signed) gives you `-64` is proof of that.

I think you may just be misunderstanding what `gdb` is doing to your input value `0xc0`. Most likely it will be loading that into a data type wider than eight bits, *without* assuming it has to sign-extend an eight-bit value.

Hence, when you print `0xc0`, it's treated as something like `0x000000c0`, very much a positive number in two's complement. When you explicitly state it should be treated as `[signed] char`, it prints the negative variant.

Comment: I got your point, but when I take a closer look. It's just by chance that `-64` in 2's complement is exactly the same as `-64` in the signed bit representation. When I first look at `-64`, I immediately thought of `1100 0000` with the first bit being the sign, which is not 2's complement but more familiar to human. Then that's is exactly `192` (surprise?). Now I stay back and calculate `-64` in 2's complement, it's all good, such coincidence amazed me